# Why Won't Garry's Mod Load my Addons?

Tags: technical-issues, mods, garrys-mod

I opened Garry's Mod earlier, and noticed that all of my addons (installed from the Steam Workshop) were missing. Not disabled, but missing: it says "None Found!" when I open the addons menu. The files seem to still be on my hard drive, and the workshop shows I'm still subscribed to them;, and they load fine in offline mode. What's going on?

Update: Aaaaaand it's working now. I think it may have been a problem with Steam/the Workshop--the in-game browser wasn't working properly before. I guess it's been fixed now.

Update 2: See my answer below.

Comment: The same here, my gmod addons are gone in the addons list and i cant download any, but the addons are still in the folder.

Comment: If you figured out the cause, can you rephrase your question to ask for solutions and/or submit your own answer? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there really is a solution, other than what I put in the second update. I'll move it to an answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen whenever the Steam workshop goes down. The only solutions I know of are either switch to offline mode or wait for it to come back online.

Answer (score 0):

I think the same thing happened to me!

it may be because garrys mod just got a major update and it deleted any extra files (or add-ons). they may restore them automatically but you probably will need to redownload them.

Comment: I can't re download them because when i click install it has a little lag spike then nothing happens. :(